# Plot the sum in Maple

Tags: complex-analysis, summation, graphing-functions, maple

Given, for $|z|\in (0,1)$

$2(1-|z|^2)^2\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(n+1)^2}{(2n+3)}\bigg(\frac{2(n+1)}{2n+3}+ (-\frac{3}{4}-\frac{7}{8})\bigg) |z|^{2n}+\frac{21}{32}$

I want to see the graph of this function. Does any one know the formula of Maple so that we can see graph in Maple?

If you know the formula please write Maple formula to see the graph of the above function.

Comment: Mapple or Maple? As I want to edit your question.

Comment: complex plot? How do we do? Could you please tell me in detail.

Comment: The best way is to use the HELP of Maple .write $> ?complexplot$